# IF Statement (This Should be Easy)

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, formulas

I'm trying to right this formula.  I thought I had it right, but obviously I don't.

What I want the formula to say is this:

If there is a date in `AK2` then return whatever that date is. But if `#NA` is in that field, then look at `AL2` and return the date in `AL2`.

Here is how I tried to write it.  It's just giving me false.  Please help

```
=IF(AK2="#NA", "AL2", IF(AK2="","AK2"))
```

Now that I look at this even more.  I would still like the formula above, but I would also like to add a third condition.  If AK2 and AL2 is blank or #NA then return `O2 + 18`.

[image]

Comment: What should the result be if `AK2` is blank and not `#N/A`? Should it be blank or should it be the value in `AL2`?

Comment: It won't ever be blank because i have a formula in the field already.  So it will either have a date in it or it will have #N/A

Comment: Fair enough. The answers below should be more than enough. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your `#N/A` check is wring, and you're missing the third paramater to `IF` in the second statament.  Try

```
=IF(ISNA(AK2),AL2, AK2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If that's a next value `#NA` then it would be like this

`=IF(AK2="#NA",AL2,AK2)`

Answer (score 0):

The above answers should be good. However, let me take it one step further. The below formula checks if the value in `AK2` is indeed a qualified date. It won't work that well, but at the very least you can rule out decimals or character strings in `AK2`. Also, it will return a specific formula if `AK2` is blank but not `#N/A`.

```
=IF(ISNA(AK2),AL2,IF(LEN(AK2)>0,IF(NOT(ISERROR(DATEVALUE(TEXT(AK2,"mm-dd-yyy")))),AK2,"Not a valid date.")))
```

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: Still not working.  I've attached some of the data that i'm using.